# Pairing Puzzle - Dropping a clue

Tags: knowledge, pattern

The eleven clues below each yield a word, ten of which may be sorted into five pairs.

- Americana band active between 1997 and 2007.
- Lived with Joey and Chandler.
- Singer did this.
- Large flat round fish with a long tail.
- A light scarf.
- Coarse hard-wearing fabric.
- A knife.
- Architecture award that rates buildings.
- A red squirrel.
- Sweet chilled and spiced wine drink.
- Carefully planned elaborate operation.

**Can you identify the pairs and determine the word which pairs with the unpaired word?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Americana band active between 1997 and 2007.

> [Shivaree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivaree_(band))

Lived with Joey and Chandler.

> [Chick Sr.](https://friends.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chick_and_The_Duck)

Singer did this.

> sang

Large flat round fish with a long tail.

> [stingaree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urolophidae)

A light scarf.

> [pugaree](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puggaree)

Coarse hard-wearing fabric.

> [dungaree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungaree_(fabric))

A knife.

> shiv

Architecture award that rates buildings.

> [Pug Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pug_Awards)

A red squirrel.

> chickaree

Sweet chilled and spiced wine drink.

> [sangaree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangaree)

Carefully planned elaborate operation.

> sting

Rule:

> Add "aree" to one word in the pair to get the other

Examples:

> shiv + aree = Shivaree
>  Chick + aree = chickaree
>  sang + aree = sangaree
>  pug + aree = pugaree
>  sting + aree = stingaree
>  ? + aree = dungaree

Therefore, the missing word is

> dung - Possible clue: animal excrement

Comment: Yes, that's it, well done!

Comment: @hexomino This was a great puzzle! I mainly tried it because I wanted to get the first clue and save someone else going through each Americana band in the Wikipedia category, but then I got rot13(Fuvinerr, puvpxnerr, fnatnerr) and started to get suspicious, especially with the answer to the third one